# Show/Hide Markers that are pulled from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, leaflet

I am using leaflet and want to show/hide the markers that are pulled from this function:

```
function showResourcesByName(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.resources.length; i++) {
        var resName = markers.resources[i].name;

        if (resName == name) {
            var resIcon = icons.resources[i].icon;
            var resSize = icons.resources[i].size;
            var resPname = icons.resources[i].pname;

            var customIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: resIcon,
                iconSize: resSize, // size of the icon
                iconAnchor:   [resSize[0]/2, resSize[1]/2], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                popupAnchor:  [2, -resSize[1]/2] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            });

            for (var j = 0; j < markers.resources[i].coords.length; j++) {
                var x = markers.resources[i].coords[j].x;
                var y = markers.resources[i].coords[j].y;

                L.marker([y, x], {icon: customIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup(resPname);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That outputs markers from a json file. To show the markers I use:
`showResourcesByName("NameOfTheMarkersHere")`

I have some ideas how this could be done, but I don't know how to make it work.

Idea #1: Add a css class to the function result, so all markers pulled from that function will have that css class, so I can toggle them on/off using javascript/css.

Idea #2: Add a way to toggle function result "on/off" in a button.

Idea #3: Put the function result inside a leaflet layer and toggle that layer on/off with a button.

Idea #4: Add a property in markers properties that can be filtered with a button when using the function.

Please, before answer take a look at my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/dVgHt4VK0DnA30M3a8vq?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I added a class to markers.

```
marker = L.marker([y, x], {icon:customIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup(resPname);

$(marker._icon).addClass('randomClass');
```

Don't forget to include jquery in your code for this to work

Here's my working plunger http://plnkr.co/edit/jVyvnNNvIzJqEn7Hm7S6?p=preview

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! It worked!
Thank you so much!